# Why cant I create the object of Console class?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to create an object of [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class, but could not succeed. I am getting this error "The constructor Console() is not visible". I also could not find any constructor in the document. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Skeet's answer is correct: you should use [`System.console()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) to get hold of the one instance of `Console`.

The reason for this is that `Console` is an implementation of the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which is used when the author of an API wants to ensure that one and only one instance of a class is ever created.

Comment: You dont have to write "Jon Skeet's answer is correct" :) It is the answer!

Comment: Heh, Jon Skeet answered before I did, but I thought I'd contribute with a bit more background so Chandi would understand *why* it's like this. Felt a bit cheeky repeating Jon's answer though!

Answer (score 2):

You're not *meant* to create instances directly. Instead, use the [`System.console()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) method:

```
Console console = System.console();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Console object, the constructor is private.

But you can obtain a Console object in this way:

```
Console console = System.console();
```

Look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create the object of the `Console` class. It is not required. Please read below from documentation :

> If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a
>   unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the
>   System.console() method. If no console device is available then an
>   invocation of that method will return null.

So, you will get the console by `System.console()` if any console device is available with Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

A Console can't be instantiated explicitely while it's constructor is private. You can access the console associated with the JVM the following way:

```
Console console = System.console();
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29).